# I'm not able to install gatsby-plugin-transition-link with npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package, gatsby

[image: Error when trying to install gatsby-plugin-transition-link]

I am currently trying to install gatsby-plugin-transition-link with npm. But it keeps throwing these error's. I have tried to research and fix the problem. But nothing I have tried has worked at all. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using React 17 by chance? https://github.com/TylerBarnes/gatsby-plugin-transition-link/issues/264

Comment: Yes I am, Is there a issue with 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a dependency issue with React 17 or v3 of gatsby, there are a few issues [like this one](http://github.com/TylerBarnes/gatsby-plugin-transition-link/issues/264) in the `gatsby-plugin-transition-link` repository. Some gatsby plugins may require some fine tuning when making this jump to React 17 or v3, the documentation can be found [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. And for the info. Unfortunately i had to learn that the hard way. But at least i know what to look for in the future. I didn't even know that different package update's a long with current React and Gatsby update's could effect each on that level. But i know now and that's what count's.